# Display specific part of very large .svg image file via javascript or css in Angular.js directive

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, angularjs-directive

I have very big map image (3000x8000px) in .png format that I have transformed to .svg for programmatic data visualization. I can not figure out how to display specific small part of that map.svg in html via css or javascript e.g on page load to display the bottom right part of .svg image. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) A)To transfer .png to .svg file I used inkscape - http://www.inkscape.org/en/ 
   B)  feImage filter of svg allows to fetch image from external source 
2) To manipulate that .svg file I used span.svg JQuery library - http://snapsvg.io/
3) For the part of the image tat you want to display:

```
var g = Snap(400,576); //size you want to 'crop'
g.attr({
   viewBox: [690, 5800, 1000, 500] //location on top left (x;y) from where to start 'cropping'
});
```